# 2 digit number in c#

Tags: c#

A need some help, I have a TextBlock that contains a string like this 00:00:00 And I want to create a timer that will count every second e.g.00:00:01 , 00:00:02 etc

So the stupid thing that I do is to take the value of the text box

```
string[] times = myTextbox.Text.Split(':');
int hours = Int32.Parse(times[0]);
int minutes = Int32.Parse(times[1]);
int seconds = Int32.Parse(times[2]);
```

Then I increase the right variable and finally I join them again and put them back in the textblock, BUT now my counter is like this: 0:0:1, 0:0:2, ...

I know the problem, its very logical but my question is how can I solve it :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of splitting the text of the textbox i would use DateTime.Parse like this:

```
var time = DateTime.Parse(myTextBox.Text);
```

then add a second:

```
time = time.AddSeconds(1);
```

and then finally, putting it back out there:

```
myTextBox.Text = time.ToString("myPattern");
```

where myPattern is replaced with any of the patterns described here: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: Thats the most right answer, to handle it like a DateTime :) I'll use yours thanks...

Comment: Man your answer the best cause I handle the string as DateTime, but you have a mistake. The AddSeconds method returns a new System.DateTime so it food be like this:
`time = time.AddSeconds(1);`

Comment: Woops, right you are. Reading your question again just made me realize that you might actually want to utilize the TimeSpan class instead of the DateTime - it seems to me you're more interested in the amount of time passed rather than one point in time. It all depends on what you're trying to represent.

Answer (score 8):

```
string displayString = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
 hours, minutes, seconds);
```

The part after the `:` is a format description. `00` means always use at least two positions and show an empty position as 0.

Answer (score 7):

When you "join them again", use `.ToString("00")` on each integer to get two digits. Alternatively, look into using a TimeSpan here.

Comment: I use a TimeSpan to create the timer, so I think TimeSpan will have some properties for formatting right? I will search it, thank for the answer.

Comment: @Andrew yes, TimeSpan has format strings for what you want (both parse and ToString)

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTimeOfTimer);

int Totalsec = span.Seconds;
           int seconds = Totalsec % 60;
           int minutes = span.Minutes;
           int hour = span.Hours;
           string Elapsedtime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",hour, minutes, seconds); that will output hour:min:sec as 00:00:00(two digit number)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following takes the string from the `TextBox`, adds 1 second and return a string of the result (including correct wrapping around minutes/hours):

```
myTextbox.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds ( TimeSpan.Parse ( myTextbox.Text ).TotalSeconds + 1 ).ToString ( "c" );
```

One remark - you need to add exception handling in case that `TextBox` is editable and might contain wrong data...

For some references see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx